# IMO Incorrect "on hold", maybe add a tag to indicate not code, but concept thinking is requested

Tags: discussion, tags

I have posted the question [App opening standard browser instead of active browser](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95759/app-opening-standard-browser-instead-of-active-browser) in the normal ProWebmaster forum.

This has been marked as off topic, which is IMO incorrect. I think my question is fit for ProWM.

I've read the ["What is on-topic"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, and the list of "these are off topic" don't apply. I'm not asking for any code, it's not a CMS, not asking for recommendations for software, it's not specific for my website and not about System & network administration.

Me the *programmer* can fix the problem with code easily, I'm not limited to a coding problem at all.

I as *webmaster* have the problem that my users end up on a page where they're not logged in and err. I'm looking for a concept where I run my website in a proper manner.

(*Apart from the request to reconsider the "on hold":*)
Maybe we need to add a tag like [concept thinking]? A brainstorm session, ProWebmaster style...?
This so we can avoid closing topics due to "too programmy", which actually aren't indented programmical at all.

Something like  [concept-thinking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concept-thinking)? I havent given it a description yet, but I will if more people like this.

Comment: I am with you brother! You made your points very well. Sometimes, we just do not know what to do with a question. I have to admit flagging a question as off-topic that ends up remaining open with good answers. The opposite can also be true. It can be a tough call sometimes. Our mods are damned good and really care about all of the OPs. However, as it is with any human endeavor, one sees something one way and another differently. We all muddle through the best we can, users and mods (just had a Westside Story / Quadrophenia flash-back - too much acid in the 70's). Cheers!!

Comment: Just to be sure, this isn't a personal attack to anyone mod at all. I think introducing this kind of tag can help up the activity in the forum, as the more advanced programmers might also request this kind of info, hard to find on the internet :)

Comment: I was sure of that! Cheers!!

Comment: I personally think your question could be a fine fit for our site, especially if it were worded to be a little less broad like "How can you guarantee the user comes back to the site in the same mobile browser after using a payment app?"    There might be API calls available that you could use, or certain payment applications might allow you pass the user agent string and support opening the correct browser again.

Answer (score 6):

*Brainstorming* and *concept thinking* unfortunately doesn't fit very well with the format of most Stack Exchange sites, which are focused on single issue/solution based questions & answers that can be voted on and accepted.

Even though this question might be answered without referencing code, it does invite a [discussion](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) based on [coding](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), both of which are considered off-topic for this site.

This might however be a suitable question for [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which lists questions about `Development methodologies and processes`, `design`, and `concepts` as being on-topic. I'll ping the mods there to ask, and will migrate if so.

In regards to the close reason, we have a limited choice of reasons and often supplement that with a relevant comment copied from our notes due to the routine number of questions we have to review. Although *programming* was cited, that likely was also meant to cover a *discussion about programming* too, which again wouldn't be considered on-topic here.

With that being said, much of what webmasters do involves programming or coding on some level, including thinking about concepts like the one you've posed. I think we could discuss expanding our guidelines to incorporate more real-world duties (e.g., in regards to coding), but questions would still need to answerable in a definitive way, so brainstorming, concept thinking, and getting input/ideas from others is really best done in our chat room, which is always great to see others helping the community in there too.

**Update:** A mod at the Programmers site relayed that it was OK to migrate, so hopefully you'll get some answers there.